How to Use Stripe Automatic Sales Tax with a Connected Account Based on the Account’s Location?
I’m working on a PHP project that uses Stripe to handle payments. Specifically, I’m using Stripe Connect to process payments on behalf of connected accounts. I need to calculate taxes automatically using Stripe’s Automatic Sales Tax feature, but I want the tax to be calculated based on the connected account’s location, not the customer’s location.
To achieve this, I’ve been temporarily updating the customer’s address to match the connected account’s address before creating the invoice, and then clearing the address afterward. This method works, but it feels like a hack, and I’m concerned about potential issues down the road.
Here’s the code I’m currently using:
function stripe_checkout($account, $user, $itemization) {
    try {
        // Temporarily update the Stripe customer's address to match the connected account's address
        $stripe->customers->update(
            $user['stripe_customer_id'],
            [
                'address' => [
                    'postal_code' => $account['postal_code'],
                    'country' => 'US',
                ]
            ]
        );

        // Prepare invoice data
        $invoice_data = [
            'customer' => $user['stripe_customer_id'],
            'auto_advance' => false,
            'collection_method' => 'charge_automatically',
            'application_fee_amount' => $account['application_fee'] * 100,
            'automatic_tax' => [
                'enabled' => true,
                'liability' => [
                    'type' => 'account',
                    'account' => $account['stripe_account_id']
                ],
            ],
            'description' => "Order",
            'on_behalf_of' => $account['stripe_account_id'],
            'transfer_data' => [
                'destination' => $account['stripe_account_id'],
            ],
        ];

        // Create the invoice but do not finalize it yet
        $invoice = $stripe->invoices->create($invoice_data);

        // Create a single invoice item for each item
        foreach ($itemization['items'] as $item) {
            $stripe->invoiceItems->create([
                'customer' => $user['stripe_customer_id'],
                'currency' => 'usd',
                'description' => $item['item_name'],
                'invoice' => $invoice->id,
                'quantity' => $item['quantity'],
                'unit_amount' => $item['adjusted_price'] * 100,
                'tax_behavior' => 'exclusive',
                'tax_code' => 'txcd_99999999'
            ]);
        }

        // Finalize the invoice
        $finalized_invoice = $stripe->invoices->finalizeInvoice($invoice->id);

        // Clear the Stripe customer's address after the transaction
        $stripe->customers->update(
            $user['stripe_customer_id'],
            [
                'address' => [
                    'postal_code' => null,
                    'country' => null,
                ]
            ]
        );

        // Return the paid invoice details
        return $finalized_invoice;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Handle errors
        return ['error' => $e->getMessage()];
    }
}


Is there a more appropriate way to calculate taxes based on the connected account’s location without modifying the customer’s address?
Am I missing a built-in Stripe feature that would handle this scenario more cleanly?
Could this temporary address change cause any potential issues with tax reporting or customer records in Stripe?

I’d appreciate any guidance or alternative approaches to solve this problem.

Stripe Tax is designed and calculated based on customer's location. Stripe doesn't have built-in support for the feature of calculating the automatic tax based on connected account's location. The customer address in invoice PDF can't be changed after the invoice is finalised. By updating the customer address to connected account's, it doesn't reflect the correct customer address in the invoice.

Another alternative is to use Tax Rates (manual tax) instead of Stripe Tax (automatic tax). Tax Rates allow configuring pre-defined tax rate for a connected account: https://docs.stripe.com/billing/taxes/tax-rates
